# calculate: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(n\theta-\sin\theta))d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

calculate: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(n\theta-\sin\theta))d\theta$
my try:

$
\begin{array}{c}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(n\theta-\sin\theta))d\theta\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta}(\frac{e^{-i(n\theta-\sin\theta)}}{2}+\frac{e^{i(n\theta-\sin\theta)}}{2})d\theta\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\frac{e^{-i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)}}{2}+\frac{e^{i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)}}{2})d\theta\\
\frac12\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}(\frac{e^{-i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)}}{2}+\frac{e^{i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)}}{2})d\theta\\
\frac14\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}(e^{-i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)}+e^{i(n\theta \cos\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)})d\theta
\end{array}$

I failed to find a path that will allow me to evaluate it. I thought about  a semi circle but I wasn't able to show the arc tends to 0.

Comment: Put $\cos\Xi=\Re e^{-i\Xi}$, then $e^{i\theta}=z$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales why, to what should I convert (cos(nθ−sinθ)? how come it's -sinθ?

Comment: @metamorphy did you mean $\cos\Xi=\Re e^{i\Xi}$?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your notation. I should not try to read these on my phone.

Comment: @metamorphy I'll get $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{cos\theta}(\mathfrak{R}e^{i(n\theta-\sin\theta)})d\theta$? how to continue from here?

Comment: @metamorphy I will get this  $\mathfrak{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n\theta-\sin\theta)+cos\theta}d\theta$ now I need to choose a path, but I cannot select a path with a negligible arch.

Comment: Now J.G. has everything written out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have incorrectly thought $e^xe^y=e^{xy}$ rather than $e^xe^y=e^{x+y}$. Your integral is$$\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta+in\theta-i\sin\theta}d\theta=\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{in\theta}e^{e^{-i\theta}}d\theta\stackrel{z=e^{-i\theta}}{=}\Re\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^zdz}{-iz^{n+1}}.$$If you want to evaluate this (you should find it's $2\pi/n!$), bear in mind the contour is clockwise.

Answer (score 7):

$$I_n(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{a\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta-a\sin\theta)d\theta
$$
Note that
\begin{align}
&I_{0}’(a)=\frac1a\int_{0}^{2\pi}d(e^{a\cos\theta}\sin(a\sin\theta))=0\implies 
I_0(a)= I_0(0)=2\pi
\end{align}

Also note $I_n’(a)=I_{n-1}(a)$, $I_{n>0}(0)=0$, and integrate
$I_n(a)=\int_0^a I_{n-1}(s)ds
$ successively  to get

$$
I_1(a)
= 2\pi a,\>\>\>
 I_2(a)=\frac{2\pi a^2}{2!},\>\>\>...\>\>\>
 I_n(a)=\frac{2\pi a^n}{n!}
$$
Thus

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta-\sin\theta)d\theta
=I_n(1)= \frac{2\pi}{n!}$$